# NVC dxDataGrid buttons column causing compiler error

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I am very new to NVC working on an existing solution. We are using a dxDataGrid, and I am trying to add a column with custom buttons. I am using the following documentation as reference:

https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/buttons/

and

https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/CommandColumnCustomization/jQuery/Light/

The existing implementation of the grid is as follows:

```
             $(function () {
                $("#branchDataGrid")
                    .dxDataGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            store: dxMvcStore({
                                key: "ID",
                            })
                        },
                        showBorders: true,
                        noDataText: "No Branch Selected",
                        editing: {
                            mode: "batch",
                            allowAdding: false,
                            allowUpdating: true,
                            allowDeleting: true
                        },
                        paging: { enabled: true, pageSize: 10 },
                        showRowLines: true,
                        sorting: { mode: "none" },
                        columns: [
                            {
                                dataField: "Name",
                                caption: "Branch/Division Name",
                                validationRules: [{ type: "required" }]
                            },
                            {
                                dataField: "Code",
                                caption: "Code",
                                validationRules: [{ type: "required" }]
                            },
                            {
                                dataField: "ExternalCode",
                                caption: "External Code",
                                validationRules: [{ type: "required" }]
                            },
                            {
                                dataField: "OrderExchangeabilityTimeoutDays",
                                caption: "Return Window (days)",
                                dataType: "number",
                                editorOptions: {
                                    format: "#",
                                    min: 1,
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                dataField: "CollectionRequestMonthlyLimit",
                                caption: "Monthly Collection Limit",
                                dataType: "number",
                                editorOptions: {
                                    format: "#",
                                    min: 1,
                                },
                                validationRules: [{ type: "required" }]
                            },
                        ],
                        onInitialized: e => {
                            self.companiesNodeDataGrid = e.component as DevExpress.ui.dxDataGrid;
                        },
                        onRowExpanding: e => {
                            // Only show one detail view at a time.
                            self.companiesNodeDataGrid.collapseAll(-1);
                        },
                        onRowInserting: e => {
                            //  self.saveCompanyResult(e, true);
                        },
                        onRowUpdating: e => {
                            //     self.saveCompanyResult(e, false);
                        }
                    }).dxDataGrid("instance");
            });
```

I am trying to add my column with the buttons as shown in the documentation. Here is a snippet:

```
                  columns: [
                            {
                                type: "buttons",
                                buttons: [{
                                   name: "save",
                                   cssClass: "my-class"
                                }]
                            },
                            {
                                dataField: "Name",
                                caption: "Branch/Division Name",
                                validationRules: [{ type: "required" }]
                            },
                            {
                                dataField: "Code",
                                caption: "Code",
                                validationRules: [{ type: "required" }]
                            },
                            {
                                dataField: "ExternalCode",
                                caption: "External Code",
                                validationRules: [{ type: "required" }]
                            },
                            {
                                dataField: "OrderExchangeabilityTimeoutDays",
                                caption: "Return Window (days)",
                                dataType: "number",
                                editorOptions: {
                                    format: "#",
                                    min: 1,
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                dataField: "CollectionRequestMonthlyLimit",
                                caption: "Monthly Collection Limit",
                                dataType: "number",
                                editorOptions: {
                                    format: "#",
                                    min: 1,
                                },
                                validationRules: [{ type: "required" }]
                            },
                        ]
```

The problem is that I am getting a compiler error in the line where it says "type: "buttons". Please see the below screenshot for reference:

[image]

I have done some searching but cannot seem to find any posts with similar issues. If anyone might have some advice for me where to look for a solution, or point out what I am doing wrong, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to continue using a different approach of adding custom markup to a column, as shown in the below link:

https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/CellCustomization/jQuery/Light/